# unable to lacate package hue

Tags: linux, package, hue

I'm trying to install Hue on Ubuntu 14, 
 it displays this :

```
apt-get install  hue 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package hue
```

anyone have an idea. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This installation script worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/cloudera/hue.git
cd hue
apt-get install python2.7-dev \
make \
libkrb5-dev \
libxml2-dev \
libxslt-dev \
libsqlite3-dev \
libssl-dev \
libldap2-dev \
python-pip

sudo apt-get install maven
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-*/_sysconfigdata_nd.py /usr/lib/python2.7/

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default

make apps
```

If you are behind a proxy server, make sure you set your environment variables correctly when installing oracle-java7 or any other package outside the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the repository doesn`t contain such package.
Try build binaries from sources: [guide](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/05/23/how-to-install-hue-hadoop-web-gui-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-lts-easy-guide/)

Comment: Thanks, I think it does not work for me because there are several tutorials that uses this command.
The guide you suggested me I already tried but I get errors when I execute the command make apps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Lucid 12.04 packages: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/precise/amd64/

The Trusty 14.04 are coming up in less than a month in CDH5.2.